# Multiple user meshes with different materials?

Tags: mesh, materials, objects

I have quite complex scene with many objects shared the same mesh (instances).
And I need to generate light-maps for entire scene and export to GLB, but without unsharing the meshes. Unsharing meshes (making single user) is not an option, because scene becomes very big and very inefficient to stream and render. I need unique materials because obviously lightmap textures will be different for each object.
Is there way in blender to make single-user materials for the same mesh? So the objects will share meshes, but not materials ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, go into the *Material* panel, click on the *Link* button and choose *Object*, you'll be able to give a different material to this object. You can also select several objects, select *Object* and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: When I switch to Object - I have to create new material and copy material content manually? I didn't find other way.
If so this would be crazy. Because i have many thousands of objects. And manual materials creation will take more than month. Is there way to automate this via script or some builtin tools maybe?

Comment: you want to copy a material? I thought you wanted a different material? could you please describe precisely? It's not clear to me...

Comment: to copy a material from an object, select the objects to which you want to assign the material, at last shift select the object you want to copy the material from, then Ctrl L > Link Materials